# Convert or store non-ascii characters properly in a MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, database, character-encoding, utf8mb4, adminer

### My Question

How can I store or convert emojis and french accents and other special non-ascii characters in a MySQL database?

### The Problem

Within the `wp_posts` table of my MySQL database called `local`, some characters in the content of the `post_content` column are emojis or french accent characters like `ë`.

When I view the field content in Adminer, the emojis are not rendered properly but the special french accent characters are:

| Content with emojis | Content with accent chars |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image: v6.1.5+5536] |

### What I've Tried

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = CONVERT(CAST(CONVERT(post_content USING latin1) AS BINARY) USING utf8)
```

^This SQL command converts most special characters but it totally nullifies (deletes all content) for the rows that have emojis or french characters.

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = CAST(CAST(CONVERT(post_content USING latin1) AS binary) AS CHAR)
```

^This SQL command successfully converts all emojis when I only run it on rows that include emojis:

| Before SQL Command | After SQL Command |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image: v6.1.5+5536] |

however, when I try to run this on the whole table, I get the following error:

```
Error in query (1366): Incorrect string value: '\xEBlle B...' for column 'post_content'
```

The command trips up once it gets to a french accent character. The `\xEBlle` is the `ë` from `Noëlle`.

### My Setup

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| Local | v6.1.5+5536 |
| Adminer | v4.8.1 |
| MySQL | v8.0.16 |
| PHP | v7.3.5 |
| Database (`local`) Collation | `utf8mb4_general_ci` |
| Table (`wp_posts`) Collation | `utf8mb4_general_ci` |
| Column (`post_content`) Collation | `utf8mb4_general_ci` |
| Column (`post_content`) Type | longtext |

Comment: it would be best that you create a fiddle wiith the charcterset that you have and the one you want with data in  it so that we have a [mre]

Comment: Specify the `utf8mb4` character set on all tables and text columns in your database, see [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/)

Comment: @nbk SQL Fiddle and DB Fiddle do not allow me to set `utf8mb4_general_ci` as the table or column Collation even though that is what's set in Adminer.

Comment: @josefZ, there is no option for plain `utf8mb4`, only options like  `utf8mb4_general_ci`, `utf8mb4_bin`, `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` and more language based (cs, da, ru, ...).

Comment: and you have utf8mb4 and what is the other charcter set or collation?

Comment: @Nbk, as mentioned in the top post, all Collations (DB, Table, and Column) are `utf8mb4_general_ci` and there is no option for just `utf8mb4`.

Comment: See "Mojibake" in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored